# How to mount a folder from a NAS drive in UBUNTU

Tags: ubuntu, mount, samba, nas

I have a NAS drive (ZYXel 320) and I am following this instruction to install the folder called Files.

I can check that when I run the following command:

```
smbclient -L //192.168.12.237
```

I am able to see the disk that I want to install:

```
Sharename       Type      Comment
    ---------       ----      -------
    public          Disk      
    video           Disk      
    photo           Disk      
    music           Disk      
    admin           Disk      
    Files           Disk      
    Volume1         Disk      
    IPC$            IPC       IPC Service (NSA320S)
Reconnecting with SMB1 for workgroup listing.

    Server               Comment
    ---------            -------

    Workgroup            Master
    ---------            -------
    WORKGROUP            NSA320S
```

then I tried to install it using this command:

```
sudo mount -t cifs -O username"??????",password="*******" //192.168.12.237/Files /mnt/nas/files
```

but then it asked me for password for root on the NAS:

```
 Password for root@//192.168.12.237/Files:  ***********
```

and when I give the password that I have, it gives me an error:

```
mount error(112): Host is down
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

What is the error? Do I need to have the admin password for NAS drive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some works, it turns out that my NAS is supporting SAMBA v1 and ubuntu trying to mount it with V2. To fix the problem, force it to mount it with ver=1.0

https://askubuntu.com/questions/915856/mounting-windows-share-using-smb-2-1-or-greater

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1474539

[How to mount a windows/samba windows share under Linux?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/99065/how-to-mount-a-windows-samba-windows-share-under-linux)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o user=_USERNAME_,uid=1000,gid=1001 //192.168.12.237/Files  /mnt/nas/files
```

Comment: This command correctly asks me to my password, but then It gives me the same error (112) Host is down. Any other idea?

Comment: what about firewall ?